# Processing Javascript in external file

Tags: javascript, java, html, processing, processing.js

This question might sound straight forward but I cant find an answer anywhere that works. Processing is a java ide and you can download a file which converts it to javascript. So far I have

```
<script src="processing.js"></script>
```

in the head tags which is the file that converts it to javascript.

I then use

```
<script type="application/processing">
    void setup() 
    {
        size(700, 600);
        background(200);
    }
</script><canvas width="700" height="600"></canvas>
```

which displays a blank gray background, 700 x 600 just like the code says.

Does anyone know how i would put the code into an external document and run it from there? i have tried saving the code as a javascript file and also trying to run it from the actual .pde file (processing). nothing works.

Comment: I tried to move your code to a seperate file, but all I got was cross-origin errors in chrome. Following the example they have [here](http://processingjs.org/learning/) / **Writing Processing Code with Javascript**  I was able to move the script code out to a seperate js file and still have it work.

Then I simply called it like so `<script src="myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my html page

Answer (score 0):

The [Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#writingpureprocessingcode) covers this.

You can simply put your code into a `.pde` file (the filetype used by the Processing IDE). Processing.js will compile this into JavaScript for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Hello Web - Processing.js Test</title>
   <script src="processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Processing.js Test</h1>
   <p>This is my first Processing.js web-based sketch:</p>
   <canvas data-processing-sources="hello-web.pde"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you could write the JavaScript directly and then include it in a separate `.js` file:

In separate file:

```
function sketchProc(processing) {
   // Override draw function, by default it will be called 60 times per second
   processing.draw = function() {
     // determine center and max clock arm length
     var centerX = processing.width / 2, centerY = processing.height / 2;
     var maxArmLength = Math.min(centerX, centerY);

     function drawArm(position, lengthScale, weight) {
       processing.strokeWeight(weight);
       processing.line(centerX, centerY,
         centerX + Math.sin(position * 2 * Math.PI) * lengthScale * maxArmLength,
         centerY - Math.cos(position * 2 * Math.PI) * lengthScale * maxArmLength);
     }

     // erase background
     processing.background(224);

     var now = new Date();

     // Moving hours arm by small increments
     var hoursPosition = (now.getHours() % 12 + now.getMinutes() / 60) / 12;
     drawArm(hoursPosition, 0.5, 5);

     // Moving minutes arm by small increments
     var minutesPosition = (now.getMinutes() + now.getSeconds() / 60) / 60;
     drawArm(minutesPosition, 0.80, 3);

     // Moving hour arm by second increments
     var secondsPosition = now.getSeconds() / 60;
     drawArm(secondsPosition, 0.90, 1);
   };
 }
```

In your html file:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
 // attaching the sketchProc function to the canvas
 var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help, the first one doesnt work, its not showing my processing file. I have put your middle code into a js file but not sure how to link it to my html. you say to put the bottom bit of code in the html but i think its javascript

Comment: @Will The bottom bit of code is JavaScript. I would put it in a script tag in your html file, or it could be in a separate file. For the first one, I'd need more information than "it's not showing". What does your JavaScript console say?

Comment: Thanks for helping. the error i get is pretty long so i took a screenshot of it, i hope thats ok, if not ill type it out [link]https://gyazo.com/22cc5cdb2ba61d9e5b8da26c8a0657d1

Comment: also the second way i put it in script tags in my html and still doesnt seem to be working and i get no errors in the console. can you confirm im coding it correctly? ive saved the js as Car.js in the same file. [link] https://gyazo.com/7478139a9e6293ff30e058080ebebc7a